# Elasticsearch script - Extraneous if statement

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using update_by_query with the following body:

```
POST /documents/_update_by_query
 {
"script":{
  "source":"for(int i = 0;i < ctx._source.fields.size();i++){for (int j = 0; j < params.field_uid.size();j++){ if(params.field_uid[j].type == \"group\" ){ } else{ if(ctx._source.fields[i].uid == params.field_uid[j].uid){ ctx._source.fields.remove(i);} } }}",
  "params":{
   "field_uid":[{"uid":"number","type":"number"},{"uid":"test","type":"group"}]
   }
 },
 "query": { 
    "term": {
      "name": "test"
    }
  }
}
```

It is giving me like Extraneous if statement. Here is the error message I got :

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "script_exception",
                "reason": "compile error",
                "script_stack": [
                    "... s.field_uid.size();j++){ if(params.field_uid[j].ty ...",
                    "                             ^---- HERE"
                ],
                "script": "for(int i = 0;i < ctx._source.fields.size();i++){for (int j = 0; j < params.field_uid.size();j++){ if(params.field_uid[j].type == 100 ){ } else{ if(ctx._source.fields[i].uid == params.field_uid[j].uid){ ctx._source.fields.remove(i);} } }}",
                "lang": "painless"
            }
        ],
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "compile error",
        "script_stack": [
            "... s.field_uid.size();j++){ if(params.field_uid[j].ty ...",
            "                             ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script": "for(int i = 0;i < ctx._source.fields.size();i++){for (int j = 0; j < params.field_uid.size();j++){ if(params.field_uid[j].type == 100 ){ } else{ if(ctx._source.fields[i].uid == params.field_uid[j].uid){ ctx._source.fields.remove(i);} } }}",
        "lang": "painless",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Extraneous if statement."
        }
    },
    "status": 500
}
```

Can anyone help me into this?
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The `if` statement written is not doing any operation and is irrelevant as a result ES is throwing `extraneous if statement` error.

Remove it and update the condition accordingly as below.

```
for(int i = 0;i < ctx._source.fields.size();i++){ for (int j = 0;j < 
params.field_uid.size();j++){ if(params.field_uid[j].type != \"group\"  
&& ctx._source.fields[i].uid == params.field_uid[j].uid){ 
ctx._source.fields.remove(i);}}}
```

Comment: Hi Chandra,

Thanks for the reply, I have one more question, How I can check startsWith in the script. I want to check if the current string starts with some other string. for example here want to check
`params.field_uid[j].type` startsWith group.name or not?